# How do I make an incremental ranking per query system on SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently on SQL Server 2019, I have the following code:

```sql
SELECT
    dbo.GroundTruth.QueryId,
    dbo.GroundTruth.Q0,
    dbo.GroundTruth.Id,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY dbo.GroundTruth.Similarity DESC) AS rank,
    dbo.GroundTruth.Similarity,
    dbo.GroundTruth.StValue FROM GroundTruth
    ORDER BY dbo.GroundTruth.QueryID ASC
```

that returns something like this this:

```
2639                 Q0   68556       118406               78.29591                                STANDARD
2639                 Q0   68582       143678               77.34721                                STANDARD
264                  Q0   6952        91193                79.59099                                STANDARD
264                  Q0   6951        207182               75.00000                                STANDARD
264                  Q0   6950        18046                88.25763                                STANDARD
2640                 Q0   68598       23812                87.26044                                STANDARD
2640                 Q0   68600       23776                87.27147                                STANDARD
2641                 Q0   68662       39200                84.62848                                STANDARD
2641                 Q0   68609       177816               76.06838                                STANDARD
```

However, I want the `QueryID` (1st) column to be ordered incrementally (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) instead of the current form (1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000) and I want the `rank` (4th) column to have ranks like this:

```
QueryID     ...     DocID     ...     rank     ...
1           ...     123       ...     1        ...
1           ...     247       ...     2        ...
1           ...     9876      ...     3        ...
2           ...     23        ...     1        ...
2           ...     17        ...     2        ...
2           ...     69        ...     3        ...
2           ...     09        ...     4        ...
```

Is there a property in SQL Server 2019 able to do this or does it need to envolve several functions?

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on columns will be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. Stick to aliasing your objects and using those to qualify your columns.

Comment: And write with a consistent style. You don't schema-qualify the table in your FROM clause but you do schema-qualify the columns.

Comment: If something is a number, store it as a number. Don't store numbers in `varchar` columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueryId` appears to be a string.  You can convert that to an int.  For the ranking, you want that per `QueryId`, so use `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT gt.*,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY gt.QueryId ORER BY gt.SImilarity DESC) as rank
FROM GroundTruth gt
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(int, gt.QueryID) ASC;
```

(This uses `gt.*` to focus on the columns you care about in the question.  In general, though, use table aliases so queries are easier to write and read.)

If you want the `QueryId` actually replaced with an enumerated value, then use:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY gt.QueryId)
```

I'm not sure if you would want such an ordering based on the string or the number value of the string.  For number sorting, you can use:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, gt.QueryId))
```

(This all assumes that `int` is big enough for the values.  If not use `NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL`.)